# try and except do not work with tensorflow exceptions

Tags: python, tensorflow

You'll need this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PsPyJNCwOen5RVI3wQ0g2VrHLrrytaE3?usp=sharing) to reproduce the error which downloads the files below and runs the exact same code following the description.

- `labels.csv`: each row contains `x0`, `y0`, `x1`, `y1` text coordinates, and other columns not affecting the outcome.
- `yolo-train-0.tfrecord`: Contains 90% of the examples found in `labels.csv`. Each example contains all labels/rows corresponding to the image in the example.

I'm experiencing a recurring error that happens when iterating over a tfrecord dataset.
After 2000-4000 iterations that successfully read batches from the dataset, I get the following error:

```
iteration: 3240 2022-02-14 04:25:15.376625: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at scatter_nd_op.cc:219 : INVALID_ARGUMENT: indices[189] = [6, 30, 38, 0] does not index into shape [8,38,38,3,6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 800, in __next__
    return self._next_internal()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/iterator_ops.py", line 786, in _next_internal
    output_shapes=self._flat_output_shapes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2845, in iterator_get_next
    _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 7107, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: indices[189] = [6, 30, 38, 0] does not index into shape [8,38,38,3,6]
     [[{{function_node __inference_transform_targets_for_output_1051}}{{node TensorScatterUpdate}}]] [Op:IteratorGetNext]
```

It is near impossible to tell which exact inputs that are causing the issue thanks to tensorflow's brilliant graph execution. I tried using `pdb`, `tf.print` statements and many other desperate measures trying to identify which examples in `labels.csv` that cause the problem and need to be excluded, and nothing looks particularly suspicious.

Here's what the notebook runs and eventually results in the error mentioned.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


def transform_images(x, image_shape):
    x = tf.image.resize(x, image_shape)
    return x / 255


@tf.function
def transform_targets_for_output(y_true, grid_size, anchor_indices):
    n = tf.shape(y_true)[0]
    y_true_out = tf.zeros((n, grid_size, grid_size, tf.shape(anchor_indices)[0], 6))
    anchor_indices = tf.cast(anchor_indices, tf.int32)
    indexes = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
    updates = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
    idx = 0
    for i in tf.range(n):
        for j in tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[1]):
            if tf.equal(y_true[i][j][2], 0):
                continue
            anchor_eq = tf.equal(anchor_indices, tf.cast(y_true[i][j][5], tf.int32))
            if tf.reduce_any(anchor_eq):
                box = y_true[i][j][0:4]
                box_xy = (y_true[i][j][0:2] + y_true[i][j][2:4]) / 2
                anchor_idx = tf.cast(tf.where(anchor_eq), tf.int32)
                grid_xy = tf.cast(box_xy // (1 / grid_size), tf.int32)
                indexes = indexes.write(
                    idx, [i, grid_xy[1], grid_xy[0], anchor_idx[0][0]]
                )
                updates = updates.write(
                    idx, [box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3], 1, y_true[i][j][4]]
                )
                idx += 1
    return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(y_true_out, indexes.stack(), updates.stack())


def transform_targets(y, anchors, anchor_masks, size):
    y_outs = []
    grid_size = size // 32
    anchors = tf.cast(anchors, tf.float32)
    anchor_area = anchors[..., 0] * anchors[..., 1]
    box_wh = y[..., 2:4] - y[..., 0:2]
    box_wh = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(box_wh, -2), (1, 1, tf.shape(anchors)[0], 1))
    box_area = box_wh[..., 0] * box_wh[..., 1]
    intersection = tf.minimum(box_wh[..., 0], anchors[..., 0]) * tf.minimum(
        box_wh[..., 1], anchors[..., 1]
    )
    iou = intersection / (box_area + anchor_area - intersection)
    anchor_idx = tf.cast(tf.argmax(iou, axis=-1), tf.float32)
    anchor_idx = tf.expand_dims(anchor_idx, axis=-1)
    y = tf.concat([y, anchor_idx], axis=-1)
    for anchor_indices in anchor_masks:
        y_outs.append(transform_targets_for_output(y, grid_size, anchor_indices))
        grid_size *= 2
    return tuple(y_outs)


def read_example(
    example,
    feature_map,
    class_table,
    max_boxes,
    image_shape,
):
    features = tf.io.parse_single_example(example, feature_map)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(features['image'], channels=3)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, image_shape)
    object_name = tf.sparse.to_dense(features['object_name'])
    label = tf.cast(class_table.lookup(object_name), tf.float32)
    label = tf.stack(
        [tf.sparse.to_dense(features[feature]) for feature in ['x0', 'y0', 'x1', 'y1']]
        + [label],
        1,
    )
    padding = [[0, max_boxes - tf.shape(label)[0]], [0, 0]]
    label = tf.pad(label, padding)
    return image, label


def read_tfrecord(
    fp,
    classes_file,
    image_shape,
    max_boxes,
    shuffle_buffer_size,
    batch_size,
    anchors,
    masks,
    classes_delimiter='\n',
):
    text_initializer = tf.lookup.TextFileInitializer(
        classes_file, tf.string, 0, tf.int64, -1, delimiter=classes_delimiter
    )
    class_table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(text_initializer, -1)
    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(fp)
    dataset = files.flat_map(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
    feature_map = {
        'image': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'x0': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'y0': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'x1': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'y1': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.float32),
        'object_name': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
        'object_index': tf.io.VarLenFeature(tf.int64),
    }
    return (
        dataset.map(
            lambda x: read_example(x, feature_map, class_table, max_boxes, image_shape),
            tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE,
        )
        .batch(batch_size)
        .shuffle(shuffle_buffer_size)
        .map(
            lambda x, y: (
                transform_images(x, image_shape),
                transform_targets(y, anchors, masks, image_shape[0]),
            )
        )
        .prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_shape = (608, 608, 3)
    labels = pd.read_csv('labels.csv')
    classes_file = 'classes.txt'
    max_boxes = max([g[1].shape[0] for g in labels.groupby('image')])
    shuffle_buffer_size = 256
    batch_size = 8
    anchors = np.array(
            [
                (10, 13),
                (16, 30),
                (33, 23),
                (30, 61),
                (62, 45),
                (59, 119),
                (116, 90),
                (156, 198),
                (373, 326),
            ]
        ) / np.array(input_shape[:-1])
    masks = np.array([[6, 7, 8], [3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2]])
    train_dataset = read_tfrecord(
                '/content/yolo-train-0.tfrecord',
                classes_file,
                input_shape[:-1],
                max_boxes,
                shuffle_buffer_size,
                batch_size,
                anchors,
                masks,
            )
    for i, _ in enumerate(train_dataset, 1):  # There should be around 11000 iterations
        print(f'\riteration: {i}', end='')
```

Is there a way to filter out the problematic examples?

I tried the following using try and except blocks and it doesn't work and gives the exception being specified despite adding the following to `create_tfrecord`

```
dataset = iter(dataset)
while True:
    try: 
        yield next(dataset)
    except InvalidArgumentError:
        pass
```

Comment: Can you use eager execution for debugging (e.g. by removing the `@tf.function` decorator)? This might help you to identify the exact issue. At least the error messages will be more verbose.

Comment: I tried removing `tf.function` however, I get the same result. You can try the colab [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PsPyJNCwOen5RVI3wQ0g2VrHLrrytaE3?usp=sharing) if you need to see for yourself.

Comment: I disagree that it's "near impossible to tell" which inputs are causing an issue. First you should remove shuffling and any other sources of non-determinism. Then do one batch at a time. Does it always occur in the same batch? What example in the batch is it (e.g. in the error it seems to be 189, but I haven't read the code in detail)? The error is quite clear in that your indices are sometimes invalid (outside the grid size). Also note that datasets support a function to skip inputs that result in error: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/ignore_errors

Comment: @xdurch0 I think it's always the same 2 batches every time however by printing the batch at every iteration, the one before the error looks just the same as the rest. Regarding the `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors` it doesn't work, I tried it and the error still occurs with zero differences.

Comment: Totally agree with @xdurch0 and you should try catching with Tensorflow errors `tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError`, which works.

Comment: @AloneTogether I already included in my question that I tried specifically catching the very same error `tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError` and the result is I get a `tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError` however nonsensical this sounds.

Comment: Oof, can you maybe try using a blank `except` just to see what happens? Also note that `tf.data` _always_ executes in graph mode, not eagerly, so actually it should make no difference whether you are using `tf.function` or not (but it also makes it hard to debug...). Another way to debug, although likely very cumbersome, could be to call the processing functions outside the `Dataset` context where you can run functions "normally" line-by-line...

Comment: Also, maybe you can find something helpful here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30653

Comment: @xdurch0 a bare except did the trick I guess, I'm only getting error notification messages and training continues. I'll try to figure things out, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the `transform_targets_for_output` method with a `try-except-raise` clause and applying `tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors` to the dataset seems to actually work:

```
def transform_targets_for_output(y_true, grid_size, anchor_indices):
    try:
      n = tf.shape(y_true)[0]
      y_true_out = tf.zeros((n, grid_size, grid_size, tf.shape(anchor_indices)[0], 6))
      anchor_indices = tf.cast(anchor_indices, tf.int32)
      indexes = tf.TensorArray(tf.int32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
      updates = tf.TensorArray(tf.float32, 1, dynamic_size=True)
      idx = 0
      for i in tf.range(n):
          for j in tf.range(tf.shape(y_true)[1]):
              if tf.equal(y_true[i][j][2], 0):
                  continue
              anchor_eq = tf.equal(anchor_indices, tf.cast(y_true[i][j][5], tf.int32))
              if tf.reduce_any(anchor_eq):
                  box = y_true[i][j][0:4]
                  box_xy = (y_true[i][j][0:2] + y_true[i][j][2:4]) / 2
                  anchor_idx = tf.cast(tf.where(anchor_eq), tf.int32)
                  grid_xy = tf.cast(box_xy // (1 / grid_size), tf.int32)
                  indexes = indexes.write(
                      idx, [i, grid_xy[1], grid_xy[0], anchor_idx[0][0]]
                  )
                  updates = updates.write(
                      idx, [box[0], box[1], box[2], box[3], 1, y_true[i][j][4]]
                  )
                  idx += 1
      return tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(y_true_out, indexes.stack(), updates.stack())
    except tf.errors.InvalidArgumentError:
        raise
```

Using a batch size of 8, I was able to iterate through the dataset successfully:

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
for i, _ in enumerate(train_dataset, 1):  # There should be around 11000 iterations
  print(f'\riteration: {i}', end='')
```

```
iteration: 11244
```

Comment: I also managed to make it work using a try and bare except, still trying to figure out how to identify examples that cause the problem so I can avoid their presence in dataset in the future

Comment: But that is exactly what `train_dataset = train_dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())
` is doing..According to the docs: "Use this transformation to produce a dataset that contains the same elements as the input, but silently **drops** any elements that caused an error"

Comment: I tried `dataset.apply(tf.data.experimental.ignore_errors())` and it didn't work, maybe this has something to do with being experimental.

Comment: Weird, because I ran it in Google Colab, as you are also, and did not get any errors. Or what exactly did not work?

Comment: Then I'll give it another shot, maybe I missed something.

Comment: Yeah I know, thanks

Comment: it worked, I'm still trying to avoid getting any errors in the first place